# Knapsack 01 solution

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

Solution to bounded knapsack 01 problem. Once again comprehensive description is difficult in this space, refer [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_Knapsack_Problem). Looking for code review. optimizations and best practices.

```
final class Item {
    private final int value;
    private final int weight;

    public Item (int value, int weight) {
        if (value == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The value " + value + " should be positive.");
        }
        if (weight == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The weight " + weight + " should be positive.");
        }

        this.value = value;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
}

public final class Knapsack01 {

    private Knapsack01() {  }

    /**
     * Returns the maximum value, given set of items and maxweight
     * 
     * @param items         the set of items.
     * @param maxWeight     the max weight
     * @return              the max value obeying the constraints
     */
    public static int getMaxValue (Item[] items, int maxWeight) {
        if (maxWeight <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("the maxweight: " + maxWeight + " should be positive");
        }

        int[][] knapsack = new int[items.length + 1][maxWeight + 1];

        for (int item = 0; item <=items.length; item++) { 
            for (int weight = 0;  weight <= maxWeight; weight++) {

                if (item == 0 || weight == 0) { 
                    continue;
                }

                int itemWeight = items[item - 1].getWeight();
                if (weight >= itemWeight) {
                    int remainingWeight = weight -  itemWeight;
                    // check the max value upto remainingWieght, the we might have computed before.
                    int valueUptoRemainingWeight = knapsack[item - 1][remainingWeight];
                    // how about trying currentItem + remainingItem ? 
                    int tentativeValue = items[item - 1].getValue() + valueUptoRemainingWeight;
                    // compare this against previously calculated max-value
                    int previousMaxValue = knapsack[item - 1][weight];

                    knapsack[item][weight] = Math.max(tentativeValue, previousMaxValue);

                } else {
                    knapsack[item][weight] = knapsack[item - 1][weight];
                 }
            }
        }

        return knapsack[items.length][maxWeight];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Item i1 = new Item( 60, 10);
        Item i2 = new Item(100, 20);
        Item i3 = new Item(120, 30);

        Item[] items = new Item[3];
        items[0] = i1;
        items[1] = i2;
        items[2] = i3;

        assertEquals(180, getMaxValue(items, 40));
        assertEquals(220, getMaxValue(items, 50));
        assertEquals(280, getMaxValue(items, 60));
        assertEquals(280, getMaxValue(items, 60));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a few comments :

---

Your `if (value == 0)` and `if (weight == 0)` should probably be `if (value <= 0)` and `if (weight <= 0)`.

---

[Keep It Simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) : because `value` and `weight` are `final`, you could probably make them public, removing the need for getters.

Also, you could make this an [inner class/nested class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_class) if you don't plan to use it for anything else.

---

Purely personal but I'd rather avoid `continue` whenever it can be easily avoided. If your case, it's quite easy to put the whole block behind a `if (item != 0 && weight != 0)` (or even better : `if (item > 0 && weight > 0)`).

However, things could be even more straightforward : `for (int item = 0; item <=items.length; item++)` and `for (int weight = 0;  weight <= maxWeight; weight++)` could start at `1` because first iteration won't do anything anyway because condition `if (item == 0 || weight == 0)` will be true. Then, as far as I can tell, the guard is not needed anymore.

Comment: simple yet meaningful :)